# Tricky multi-step subset selection

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix:

```
1 3  NA
1 2  0
1 7  2
1 5  NA
1 9 5
1 6  3
2 5  2
2 6  1
3 NA  4
4 2  9
...
```

I would like to select those elements for each number in the first column to which the corresponding value in the second column has an NA in its own second column.

So the search would go the following way:

1. look up number in the first column: 1.
2. check corresponding values in second column: 3,2,7,5,9,6...
3. look up 3,2,7,5,9,6 in first column and see if they have NA in their
   second column

The result in the above case would be:

```
>3 NA  4<
```

Since this is the only value which has NA in its own second row.

Here's what I want to do in words:

1. Look at the number in column one, I find '1'.
2. What numbers does 1 have in its second column: 3,2,7,5,9,6
3. Do these numbers have NA in their own second column? yes, 3 has an NA
4. I would like it to return those numbers not row numbers.
5. the result would be the subset of the original matrix with those rows which satisfy the condition.

This would be the matlab equivalent, where i is the number in column 1:

```
isnan(matrix(matrix(:,1)==i,2))==1)
```

Comment: not good because I want to select only those which 1 has in its second column

Comment: so it would be a stepwise thing going through each number in column1, checking its values in column 2 and checking those values in column one to see if they have NA in their second column

Comment: I would implement this in a for loop where i stands for the number in column 1, so I only need the solution for 1 number which  i can then modify

Comment: @user1723765 In step 3, do you mean "Do these row numbers have `NA` in the second column?" or do you mean, "Do the rows with these numbers have `NA` in their second column?". Also, the number 1 occurs multiple times, do you want to return `3 NA 4` as many times as there are `1` in the first column? What do you want the return value to be, a `matrix`, a `list`, a `data.frame`? It would be helpful if you "finished" the example above, showing what the final result would be. Also, when you post an example matrix, try posting something we can cut and paste into our consoles.

Comment: @user1723765: Please delete most of your comments after editing the question to include the clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `by`, to get the result by group of column 1, assuming `dat` is your data frame

```
by(dat,dat$V1,FUN=function(x){
                  y <- dat[which(dat$V1 %in% x$V2),]
                  y[is.na(y$V2),]
})

dat$V1: 1
  V1 V2 V3
9  3 NA  4
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dat$V1: 2
[1] V1 V2 V3
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dat$V1: 3
[1] V1 V2 V3
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dat$V1: 4
[1] V1 V2 V3
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

**EDIT**

Here I trie to do the same function as matlab command:

here the R equivalent of matlab

```
  isnan(matrix(matrix(:,1)==i,2))==1)   ## what is i here 

  is.na(dat[dat[dat[,1]==1,2],])        ## R equivalent , I set i =1

     V1    V2    V3
3 FALSE FALSE FALSE
2 FALSE FALSE FALSE
7 FALSE FALSE FALSE
5 FALSE FALSE FALSE
9 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
6 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: this is a terribly slow function

Comment: @user1723765 ad this terribly subjective comment. can you tell the diemnsions of your matrix and the time you spent whenyou apply the same function in MATLAB.

Comment: It has three columns and 20000 rows in matlab I haven't measured the time but it is considerably faster

Comment: this is great. this is what I'm looking for. the only thing is that I would like to be able to select only the one hwere V2 is TRUE. is theree a way to incorporate that in the code?

Comment: The second solution given by agstudy is perfect I only need something that will return only the TRUE ones from his subset

Comment: still not good , have a look at agstudy's second answer which does exactly what I was looking for

Comment: is.na(dat[dat[dat[,1]==1,2],]) this command workd perfectly but I would like to select a subset of this where V2 =TRUE

Answer (score 2):

This hopefully reads easily as it follows the steps you described:

```
idx1 <- m[, 1L] == 1L
idx2 <- m[, 1L] %in% m[idx1, 2L]
idx3 <- idx2 & is.na(m[, 2L])
m[idx3, ]
# V1 V2 V3 
#  3 NA  4
```

It is all vectorized and uses integer comparison so it should not be *terribly* slow. However, if it is too slow for your needs, you should use a `data.table` and use your first column as the key.

Note that you don't need any of the assignments, so if you are looking for a one-liner:

```
m[is.na(m[, 2L]) & m[, 1L] %in% m[m[, 1L] == 1L, 2L], ]
# [1]  3 NA  4
```

(but definitely harder to read and maintain.)

Answer (score 0):

I am still not totally clear as to what you want, but maybe this would work?

```
m<-read.table(
textConnection("1 3  NA
1 2  0
1 7  2
1 5  NA
1 9 5
1 6  3
2 5  2
2 6  1
3 NA  4
4 2  9"))

do.call(rbind,lapply(split(m[,2],m[,1]),function(x) m[x[!is.na(x)][is.na(m[x[!is.na(x)],2])],]))

#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  3 NA  4
```

It would be much nicer if you provided an example that you want to have more than one row.

Comment: this takes terribly long and is very inelegant. why is it much easier to do in matlab?